# Why Spark use CodeGen technology to generate subclasses of UnsafeProjection

Tags: apache-spark-sql

From my perspective, spark uses `CodeGen` mainly for optimization like merging serveral Functions into single one, but there's something different, like generating `SpecificUnsafeProjection`, no functions merged, so maybe we can ***hardcode*** `SpecificUnsafeProjection` directly instead of through `CodeGen`. Why Spark chooses `CodeGen` here?

Comment: What's `SpecificUnsafeProjection`? A link to the sources @ master would be of much help.